# Variation of Parameters to find solution to matrix exponential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been trying to arrive at the solution to this problem and I seem to be making a mistake somewhere. I want to solve this:

So $$
        x' =\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        0 & -2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}x+\begin{pmatrix}e^{-2t}\\0 \end{pmatrix}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ x(0)=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
I used a Laplace transform to arrive at $$e^{\mathbf At}=\begin{pmatrix}
        e^t & \frac{e^t-e^{-2t}}{3} \\
        0 & e^{-2t} \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
Then to find the particular solution I used the equation $\mathbf x_p(t)=e^{\mathbf A t} \int_0^t e^{-\mathbf As}\mathbf g(t)ds$. So,

$$\mathbf x_p(t)=e^{\mathbf At}\int_0^t\begin{pmatrix}
        -e^s & -\frac{e^s-e^{-2s}}{3} \\
        0 & -e^{-2s} \\
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e^{-2s}\\0 \end{pmatrix}ds$$

Arriving at $\mathbf x_p(t)=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$. Is this correct up to here?

Comment: $e^{-As} \neq - e^{As}$. Note that the input is $e^{-2t} v_1$, where $v_1$ is an eigenvector of $A$ (and hence of $e^{At}$).

Comment: I think it should be $x_p(t) = { 1 \over 3} (e^t - e^{-2t}) (1,0)^T$.

Comment: Okay, so for example $v_1$ in  $e^{-At}$ should be $(e^{-t},0)^T$?

Comment: I am also curious how you got that answer for $x_p(t)$. Doesn't that disappear when multiplied by $g(t)$?

Comment: I added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $e_1 = (1,0)^T$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to an eigenvalue of $1$. It follows that $e^{tA} v_1 = e^t e_1$.

$x_p(t) = \int_0^t e^{(t-s)A} e^{-2s} e_1 ds = \int_0^t e^{(t-s)} e^{-2s} e_1 ds = \int_0^t e^{(t-3s)} e_1 ds= { 1 \over 3} (e^t - e^{-2t}) e_1$